# How do I set the Top and Left properties of a Rectangle in a Canvas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I'm developing a simple "Game" if you can even call it that, it's going to be a canvas with a rectangle that will move when you press either `W,A,S or D`

As for now it seems to be changing the rectangles Y position but it's not updating on the screen, aka the rectangle in the canvas is not moving position and I don't know why.

This is my Window.xaml

```
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding WalkForwardCommand}" Key="W"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>


    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:GameViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

<Canvas Width="792" Height="420">

    <Rectangle Name="LocalPlayer"
               Fill="Crimson"
               Width="50" Height="50"
               Visibility="{Binding LocalPlayer.IsOnline }"
               
               Canvas.Top="{Binding LocalPlayer.Y }"
               Canvas.Left="{Binding LocalPlayer.X }" />
</Canvas>
```

Here is the `GameViewModel`

```
public RelayCommand WalkForwardCommand { get; set; }

private Client _localPlayer;

public Client LocalPlayer
{
    get { return _localPlayer; }
    set
    {
        _localPlayer = value;

    }
}

public GameViewModel()
{
    

    WalkForwardCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
    {
        LocalPlayer.Y -= 5;


        Debug.WriteLine("Walking up...");
        Debug.WriteLine(LocalPlayer.Y);
    });
}
```

And the Client.cs

```
class Client : ObservableObject
{
    public int X { get; set; }

    private int y;

    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set
        {
            y = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And of course, the ObservableObject

```
class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The command is working because it's printing out to the console just fine so it's binding properly.
But for some reason the Rectangle doesnt switch position when the Y value changes.

Why is that and how do I properly fix it?

Comment: Add `LocalPlayer = new Client();` to `GameViewModel` constructor. You've forgot to instantiate the object. And call `OnProperyChanged()` inside of `LocalPlayer` setter.

Comment: Based on your example above, I tried a quick test and the rectangle goes up normally. I don't know what is the `NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator` so I had to comment it out. Also on the ViewModel I had to initialize the client as `private Client _localPlayer = new Client();`. Maybe something else is the reason?

Comment: Is it likely that you instantiate the `LocalPlayer` from the outside and then pass it to the ViewModel? If that is the case you might need to raise an `OnPropertyChanged` event inside the setter of it.

Comment: Canvas.left and top are double rather than int. Not sure that'd make any difference. You have null for y there. If you give y a value 20 or something in it's declaration, does that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make `LocalPlayer` a read-only property that you initialize using an auto-property initializer:

```
 public Client LocalPlayer { get; } = new Client()
```

Then change the type of `Y` to `double`:

```
public double Y
{
    get { return y; }
    set
    {
        y = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```